# How to use warm_start

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to use the `warm_start` parameter to add training data to my random forest classifier. I expected it to be used like this:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(...)
clf.fit(get_data())
clf.fit(get_more_data(), warm_start=True)
```

But the `warm_start` parameter is a constructor parameter. So do I do something like this?

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(get_data())
clf = RandomForestClassifier (warm_start=True)
clf.fit(get_more_data)
```

That makes no sense to me. Won't the new call to the constructor discard previous training data? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: `warm_start` is intended to be used on same data. What is your use case? You want to train the classifier in batches, small data at one time?

Comment: @VivekKumar I'd like to incrementally train the classifier. I have a base dataset, and incoming batches of newly created training data (the base set and the new batches have the same shape, I'm not adding extra features or anything like that, just more training data). Now I could re-initialise the model with the base dataset merged with the new batch of data and train on that, but that is too slow. I'd like to 'resume' the training process with the new batch of training data. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Only estimators in scikit-learn which support incremental learning are given on http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning. RandomForestClassifier is not one of them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The basic pattern of (taken from Miriam's answer):

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True)
clf.fit(get_data())
clf.fit(get_more_data())
```

would be the correct usage API-wise.

But there is an issue here.

As the docs say the following:

> When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble, otherwise, just fit a whole new forest.

it means, that the only thing `warm_start` can do for you, is adding new DecisionTree's. All the previous trees seem to be untouched!

Let's check this with [some sources](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L291):

```
  n_more_estimators = self.n_estimators - len(self.estimators_)

    if n_more_estimators < 0:
        raise ValueError('n_estimators=%d must be larger or equal to '
                         'len(estimators_)=%d when warm_start==True'
                         % (self.n_estimators, len(self.estimators_)))

    elif n_more_estimators == 0:
        warn("Warm-start fitting without increasing n_estimators does not "
             "fit new trees.")
```

This basically tells us, that you would need to increase the number of estimators before approaching a new fit!

I have no idea what kind of usage sklearn expects here. I'm not sure, if fitting, increasing internal variables and fitting again is correct usage, but i somehow doubt it (especially as `n_estimators` is not a public class-variable).

Your basic approach (in regards to this library and this classifier) is probably not a good idea for your out-of-core learning here! I would not pursue this further.

Comment: I know this is old, but - how do I approach this with a saved model? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 15):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
boston = load_iris()
X, y = boston.data, boston.target

### RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, warm_start=True)
rfc.fit(X[:50], y[:50])
print(rfc.score(X, y))
rfc.n_estimators += 10
rfc.fit(X[51:100], y[51:100])
print(rfc.score(X, y))
rfc.n_estimators += 10
rfc.fit(X[101:150], y[101:150])
print(rfc.score(X, y))
```

Below is differentiation between warm_start and partial_fit.

When fitting an estimator repeatedly on the same dataset, but for multiple parameter values (such as to find the value maximizing performance as in grid search), it may be possible to reuse aspects of the model learnt from the previous parameter value, saving time. When warm_start is true, the existing fitted model attributes an are used to initialise the new model in a subsequent call to fit.
Note that this is only applicable for some models and some parameters, and even some orders of parameter values. For example, warm_start may be used when building random forests to add more trees to the forest (increasing n_estimators) but not to reduce their number.

partial_fit also retains the model between calls, but differs: with warm_start the parameters change and the data is (more-or-less) constant across calls to fit; with partial_fit, the mini-batch of data changes and model parameters stay fixed.

There are cases where you want to use warm_start to fit on different, but closely related data. For example, one may initially fit to a subset of the data, then fine-tune the parameter search on the full dataset. For classification, all data in a sequence of warm_start calls to fit must include samples from each class.

Comment: This is working fine. Just make some sample codes and test, without adding up the n_estimators, all the fits after the first one would not change the result meanwhile adding up the n_estimators actually change the result after the new fit

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to excellent @sascha`s answer, this hackie method works:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, warm_start=True)                     
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf.n_estimators += 1
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: does this work if my X_train, y_train is different from the first fit () ? With your current code, if data in both the fits is different, classifier doesnot remember the previous fit(). It just remembers the last fit() data we trained on.

Comment: Would that automatically make the bootstrap too?

Comment: I built this logic in a loop where I iteratively increase n_estimators by 100 trees each time. I would expect that all iterations take the same amount of time to compute, since they are all doing the same: training 100 independent trees more and adding them to the ensemble. However the time increases linearly...

Answer (score 6):

All `warm_start` does boils down to *preserving the state* of the previous train.

---

It differs from a `partial_fit` in that the idea is not to incrementally learn on small batches of data, but rather to re-use a trained model in its previous state. Namely the difference between a regular call to `fit` and a fit having set `warm_start=True` is that the estimator state is not cleared, see [`_clear_state`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py#L1359)

```
if not self.warm_start:
    self._clear_state()
```

Which, among other parameters, would initialize all estimators:

```
if hasattr(self, 'estimators_'):
    self.estimators_ = np.empty((0, 0), dtype=np.object)
```

So having set `warm_start=True` in each subsequent call to `fit` will not initialize the trainable parameters, instead it will start from their previous state and add new estimators to the model.

---

Which means that one could do:

```
grid1={'bootstrap': [True, False],
 'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
 'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
 'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
 'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10]}

rf_grid_search1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = RandomForestClassifier(), 
                               param_distributions = grid1,
                               cv = 3,
                               random_state=12)
rf_grid_search1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then fit a model on the best parameters and set `warm_start=True`:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(**rf_grid_search1.best_params_, warm_start=True)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then we could perform `GridSearch` *only* on say `n_estimators`:

```
grid2 = {'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]}
rf_grid_search2 = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf,
                               param_distributions = grid2,
                               cv = 3, 
                               random_state=12,
                               n_iter=4)
rf_grid_search2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The advantage here is that the estimators would already be fit with the previous parameter setting, and with each subsequent call to `fit`, the model will be starting from the previous parameters, and we're just analyzing if adding new estimators would benefit the model.

Comment: interesting answer. Now, let's say you want to use a sklearn model that provides partial_fit, in order to do incremental learning. 

One issue can be: The number of features for the model can increase over time. And with new features, you might need to re train the model from scratch, while you were making partial_fit for weeks... However, if you set warm_start=True, and combine it with partial fit, you can change the number of features over time, and never need to re-train from zero. Don't you agree?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that @nolw38 you could give it a go to check. My guess is that is should be possible for certain models? For instance a random forest could be ok with this since it is only training on a fixed size subset of features, so the new estimators will be trained on equally sized arrays. Though there might be some check or something that I'm not thinking of. Let me know if you try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

as @sascha pointed out, the previously fitted trees are untouched, and you need to add new estimators before calling fit again. he seemed unsure how to change it, as it is a public variable. the api provides a function called set_params() which allows this.
here's how i've done it in the past:

```
training_data = list(random.sample(list(zip(INPUT, OUTPUT)), min([int(len(INPUT) * 0.80), 1300]))) 
# get either 80% of the data or 1300 samples, whichever is smaller
__INPUT=[]
__output=[]
for _I, o in training_data:
   __INPUT.append((_I))
   __output.append(o)
# re-split our random sample of tuples into 2 lists
regressor.fit(__INPUT, __output)
# first fit
est = int(int(len(regressor.estimators_) * random.choice([1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.1, 1.11, 1.13, 1.1, 1.11, 1.13]))) 
# get current estimators times a number between 1.1 and 1.5...theres a better way to write this, but im putting the shitty version here for the copy-pasta people
print('Planting additional trees...', est - len(regressor.estimators_))
regressor = regressor.set_params(n_estimators=est, warm_start=True)
regressor.fit(__INPUT, __output)
# new trees fit
```