# how to use warm_start Parameters？

Tags: python

I'd like to use the warm_start parameter to add training data to my random forest Regressor.Now, I have 100 different files.I don't want to make these to a very big file and I expected it to be used like this：

```
regr_rf = RandomForestRegressor(warm_start=True)
for i in range(100):
    #rf_train and rf_target are created
    regr_rf.fit(rf_train, rf_target)
joblib.dump(regr_rf, 'reg_RF_train_QPE_model.pkl')
```

I think the model will be bigger than last time,but it isn't.
how can I change this code to achieve my idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use warm\_start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757892/how-to-use-warm-start)

Comment: but this question didn't solve.And I don't konw if I can use this parameter to add training data,