# How to save model in random forest and continue training with new data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I have a random forest, which I want to train on different datasets.

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,
                              random_state=Zufallszahl,
                              bootstrap= True,
                              criterion="mse",
                              max_features=None,
                              #max_leaf_nodes=None,
                              max_samples = None,
                              min_samples_leaf=5,
                              min_samples_split=40,
                              warm_start=True
                              )
```

I have already seen people save the model with:

```
filename = 'random_forest_1.sav'
pickle.dump(regressor, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

and then load it with

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

This also works for my example, but I want to train the model again after i load it.

So i thought it should look something like:

```
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
     regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)                             #Where x_train, y_train is from the new dataset
```

I did the same with a neural net, where i saved the weights and continued to train with them and it worked, but for the random forest i do not seem to know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **warm_start=True** - quote - *When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble, otherwise, just fit a whole new forest.*

Check for more detials:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html

Comment: It should be noted that according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757892/how-to-use-warm-start) `warm_start` does not modify existing trees, it can only grow additional ones, and sklearn implementation of `RandomForestRegressor` does not provide `partial_fit()`. At least, that's how it worked in the older versions.

Comment: But if I use `warm_start`, does it take the old trees into account if i fit the model with a new dataset?

Comment: Quote - "When warm_start is true, the existing fitted model attributes are used to initialize the new model in a subsequent call to fit."- link https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-warm_start